# partial page rendering (PPR) with faces-redirect

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 and I faced a problem with partial page rendering. I need to load content from a Facelet file into "dynamic" part of a template.

`index.xhtml`:

```
<f:view> 
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:outputPanel layout="block">
            <p:commandButton action="content-2?faces-redirect=false" update="display" />
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel id="display" layout="block">
            content 1
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

`content-2.xhtml`:

```
<h:body>
    content 2 loaded
</h:body>
```

When I click on the `<p:commandButton>`, then `content-2.xhtml` will be opened. However, this refreshes the whole page. The XML response contains like this:

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewRoot">
```

When I change the `action` attribute to a method expression:

```
<f:view> 
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:outputPanel layout="block">
            <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.increment}" update="display" />
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel id="display" layout="block">
            #{myBean.count}
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Then the `display` block updates as expected. The XML response contains like this:

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="form:display">
```

Why does the `action="content-2?faces-redirect=false"` way update the entire page?

I also tried to `<ui:composition>`, but in this case this reloads "static" part of template. I do not want it.

Comment: Are you implying that `#{myBean.method}` returns `content-2.xhtml`? The `faces-redirect=false` is the default already, I don't understand why you're explicitly mentioning this. Are you implying that `action="content-2.xhtml"` behaves differently?

Comment: No, sorry, i did update part which with #{myBean.method}. Method body looks like `count++`. And i try `action="content-2.xhtml"` its also refresh `javax.faces.ViewRoot` but `action="#{myBean.increment}"` refresh `display`. I thought what `faces-redirect=false` must have assignment `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fully normal and expected behavior if you **navigate** to a different view by supplying a non-`null` outcome in the `action` attribute. JSF will then overrule the partial render with a render of `@all`. JSF/Facelets won't somehow automagically retain the common components in the tree as you seemed to expect. If you intend to dynamically *change* the component tree during a partial page rendering, then you need inside the `<p:outputPanel id="display" layout="block">` either a dynamic include something like this (`section` is just an integer)

```
<ui:include src="section#{bean.section}.xhtml" />
```

or multiple conditionally rendered sections

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.section == 1}"><ui:include src="section1.xhtml" /></ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.section == 2}"><ui:include src="section2.xhtml" /></ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.section == 3}"><ui:include src="section3.xhtml" /></ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.section == 4}"><ui:include src="section4.xhtml" /></ui:fragment>
```

Each has its own pros and cons depending on whether the include file contains form/input/command components and/or references view scoped beans. The `<ui:include>` runs namely during view build time like JSTL. See for more detail also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

The presence of `faces-redirect=false` is not significant as it's the default already. If it were `true`, then a JavaScript `window.location` would be invoked on the target URL.

Comment: Thanks, think i understand now. I thought how i can do so what all blocks on the page will might update independently of state of the server.